# How Oracle.DataAccess.dll determine the C# assembly to use when returning an object

Tags: c#, oracle, dll

I have a C# app that connect to an Oracle database using Oracle.DataAccess.dll.
In the application folder there are 2 dlls which both contain the same classes for a UDT that gets returned by a method in the oracle code.
Only one of these dlls is included as a reference on the C# project but the returned object matches up with the classes in the other dll. If I remove the unwanted dll then it returns the correctly matched up object. How does the Oracle.DataAccess.dll determine which C# dll to use?

using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

....

```
returnedObject.UdtTypeName = "XXX.YYY";
command.Parameters.Add(returnedObject);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
return ((IXXX)returnedObject.Value);
```

The last line errors as the returnedObject.Value is a IXXX from the other dll, not the one referenced in this project.

Comment: I don't think this is specific for `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. Have a look at [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)

Comment: `IXXX.GetType().Assembly.Location` should show the related DLL